# Java stopwatch class

Tags: java

Okay so I am trying to add methods this stopwatch class to pause and resume the time on the stopwatch. The stopwatch works fine and so does the resume method. The problem is with the pause method. 
When I use elapsedTime to check how much time has passed and then the pause method to pause the time and then I wait for a little bit and check the time again, the time paused. However if I then wait for a little bit and check the time again by using elapsedTime (without using pause() again) the time changes as if I had resume the time. If I check time, pause, check time, pause,...  then the time does not change but obviously I want the time to stay paused until I resume.

```
public class Stopwatch {
  private final long start;
  private long additionalTime;
  private long pauseStart;

  public Stopwatch() {
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();}

  public void pause() {
   if (pauseStart == 0) 
     pauseStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

  public void resume() {
   if (pauseStart != 0) {
     long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - pauseStart;
     additionalTime += stopTime;
     pauseStart = 0;
    }
}

  public double elapsedTime() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (pauseStart != 0) {
       long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - pauseStart;
       additionalTime += stopTime;
       pauseStart = 0;
    }

    return ((now - start) - additionalTime) / 1000.0;}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    double total = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) 
      total += Math.random();

    double time = watch.elapsedTime();

    StdOut.println(timi);

    watch.pause();

     for (int i = 0; i < 200000000; i++) 
      total += Math.random();

     time = watch.elapsedTime();

    StdOut.println(time);

    for (int i = 0; i < 200000000; i++) 
      total += Math.random();

    time = watch.elapsedTime();

    StdOut.println(time);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use two different classes. Have you considered something like this?

- Rename your Stopwatch class to, let's say: InnerStopwatch.
- Create a new Stopwatch class that holds a List of InnerStopwatchs.
- When you **start** a Stopwatch, it creates a new InnerStopwatch, starts it and stores a reference to it as your "current inner stopwatch"
- When you **pause** the Stopwatch, it calls the stop method on the "current inner stopwatch".
- When you **resume** the Stopwatch, it creates a new InnerStopwatch and starts it; and marks it as the new "current inner stopwatch"
- When you ask for the **elapsed time**, than it sums the elapsed times of all inner stopwatchs in the List.

Please let me know if that works for you.